# Notepad++ - how to replace 1 character if a condition is true

Tags: regex, notepad++, srt

I am correcting a few subtitles (.srt files) on Notepad++.

**The problem I want to solve:** some phrases (subtitles) have an '.' (endpoint) on the end of the line, but the phrase continues to the next subtitle (a few lines down, after a line with the subtitle index and a line with the time code).

---

**What I want to do:** I want to remove the endpoint of a line IF the next subtitle (a few lines below) start with a lower case character [a-z]

---

**Example:**

**I want to turn this:**

124
01:09:01,200 --> 01:09:02,800
Luke, I am.

125
01:09:02,800 --> 01:09:04,900
your father.

**into this:**

124
01:09:01,200 --> 01:09:02,800
Luke, I am

125
01:09:02,800 --> 01:09:04,900
your father.

---

**What I got so far:** I can find the endpoints I want to remove, using this REGEX code:

Find:

```
(\.)+(\n\n[0-9][0-9][0-9]\r\n[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9] --> [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]\r\n[a-z])
```

But I can't understand what should I put in the **'Replace'** field.
I want to replace ONLY the endpoint (.)

Please excuse me if this is a 'dumb' question, I'm trying it for a weak and I can't figure it out, I'm a total newbie in regex.
Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
If a leave the Replace field in blank, It removes all of this:
.
subtitle index (125)
subtitle timecode (01:09:02,800 --> 01:09:04,900)

Comment: As an answer to your question, you should put `$2` in the replacement, see https://regex101.com/r/RBhH1k/1 but I would recommend using one of the given anwers which also take the different newlines into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex expression `\.(?=\R+\d+\R+.*?\R+[a-z])` and check "Match case", "Wrap around" and "Regular expression" and leave the replacement text empty.

- `\.`  matches the end point
- `(?=<expression>)` is a look ahead. I.e., it must match but is not part of the search result and will therefore not be replaced.
- `\R+` matches end of line characters (at least one).
- `\d+` is the number.
- `.*?` is any number of any character, but as few as possible. This stands for the time range but will not swallow the following patterns (because of the `?`).
  `[a-z]` matches the lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you very much, Olivier.
That did the trick perfectly.
Now I'll try to learn a little more using your formula in different situations.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.(?=\R\R[\d:,\s\->]+?\R[a-z])`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.              # a dot
(?=             # lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \R\R            # 2 any kind of linebreak
    [\d:,\s\->]+?   # 1 or more digit, colon, comma, space, hyphen, greater than
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
    [a-z]           # a lowercase letter
)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: As I understand the question, the endpoint must only be removed if the next text starts with a lower case letter. Here It must be removed from "Like, I am.", because "your father." starts with a lower case letter and is therefore assumed to  be a continuation of the sentence.

Comment: Probably the lookahead must be `\R+\d+\R+.*?\R+[a-z]` and *Match case* must be checked.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Tout à fait. J'ai mal compris ;(

Comment: Thanks to all of you.
Thanks also for the explanation, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Vnov: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why there are 3 deleted answers before me but this would do it:

```
\.(?=[\r\n]+\d+[\r\n]+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+ --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d+[\r\n]+[a-z])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you @MonkeyZeus.
now I think I get it why it wasn't working!

Comment: @Vnov You're welcome! Additionally you could substitute `[\r\n]+` with just `\R+` as I'm seeing in other posts.